# What is the cause of the 'not found' error in my user-defined function?

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
df <- tibble(wspid = c("text","text",1:9,NA),
             PID = c("text","text",1:10))

#Function to export a single column inputted in the function argument
export_ids <- function(var) {
  
  export_df <- df %>%
    filter(!is.na(var)) %>%
    select(var)

  write_csv(export_df, "~/Downloads/final_ids.csv")

}

#Calling the function
export_ids(wspid)
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `!is.na(var)`.
x object 'wspid' not found
```

I suspect there's some issue with the scoping of the function but no matter what combinations I try-- such as defining the tibble within the function or referencing the tibble directly within the function (as in, df$var) I still get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we pass unquoted variable, use `{{}}` (curly-curly opertor) for evaluation

```
export_ids <- function(var) {
  
  export_df <- df %>%
    filter(!is.na({{var}})) %>%
    select({{var}})

  write_csv(export_df, "~/Downloads/final_ids.csv")

}
```

-testing

```
export_ids(wspid)
```

Comment: Is the best practice to use the curly-curly operator or to pass the argument in quotes? And can you explain why quotes/curly-curly are required?

Comment: @StephenPoole your example is using tidyverse approach, so the recommended option for non-standard evaluation would be `{{}}` i.e. when you pass as unquoted argument.  or else have to convert to quosure (`enquo`) or symbol (`ensym`) and evaluate (`!!`).  Other options include `.data[[`, but this requires a string input (quoted)

Answer (score 1):

I guess a better solution would be to simply use:

```
df <- tibble(wspid = c("text","text",1:9,NA),
             PID = c("text","text",1:10))

#Function to export a single column inputted in the function argument
export_ids <- function(df, var) {
    data <- df[[var]]
    # now filter out NA values
    data <- data[!is.na(data)]
    write_csv(data, "~/Downloads/final_ids.csv")
}

#Calling the function
export_ids(df, "wspid")
```